# Did Giordano Bruno say this quote about swimming against the torrent?

Tags: quotes

I recently saw an image where this quote

> Non temete nuotare contro il torrente, è d'un anima sordida pensare come il volgo, perché il volgo è in maggioranza

is attributed to 16th Century Italian philosopher [Giordano Bruno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giordano_Bruno).

Searching [for it on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Non%20temete%20nuotare%20contro%20il%20torrente%2C%20%C3%A8%20d%27un%20anima%20sordida%20pensare%20come%20il%20volgo%2C%20perch%C3%A9%20il%20volgo%20%C3%A8%20in%20maggioranza%22) returns several results (mostly people using it as "signature" in discussion forums, [this](https://www.positanonews.it/2009/04/salerno-la-caduta-estetica-di-daniel-oren/3078/) article, and the quote at the beginning of [this book](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Saggio_sulla_rivoluzione)) attributing it to Giordano Bruno, but I can't find it anywhere on [Wikiquote](https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Giordano_Bruno) (for example).

The sentence can be translated to:

> Do not be afraid to swim against the torrent [i.e. upstream], it is of a sordid soul to think like the common people, because the common people are always the majority.

Did Giordano Bruno ever said anything to that effect?

Comment: Well, more than two dozen of [Bruno's works](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bruno/#WorkBrun) in Italian and Latin survive, however, I can find no particular mention of this in McIntyre's 1903 opus [_Giordano Bruno_](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46901/46901-h/46901-h.htm).

Comment: @bishop - so..... must be Einstein?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Clearly. :p My hope is another soul will brave the collected works and provide a more definite answer.

Comment: side note: if the stream is turbulent, if you are dead you can swim upstream rather easily
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZBWnhzYvts

Comment: @EarlGrey but only if you are (or were) a trout and are being towed upstream.

Comment: @phoog the trout is not towed, it is tethered. There is a huge difference between the two terms.

Comment: @EarlGrey if the trout is tethered then it is not moving upstream but remaining in the same place.  It would only move upstream if it were towed.

Comment: @phoog you are welcome to present your peer-reviewed research and to write your rebuttal to Beal et al., 
https://fyfluiddynamics.com/2018/07/when-i-was-a-child-my-father-would-take-me-trout/?doing_wp_cron=1690976426.6408770084381103515625

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He said something like it (possibly the same thing), then later penned a book that says a similar thing (and much else in the same vein). Both speech and later book are in Latin, so the quote in Italian is neccessarily not the true wording.

There is [a citation site](https://citaty.net/autori/giordano-bruno/?page=3) that describes the provenance of the quote (or something very similar, we are talking about the translation of a quote after all) as such:

> Included as a quotation in The Great Quotations (1977) by George
> Seldes, p. 35, this appears to be a paraphrase of a summation of
> arguments of Bruno's speech in a debate at the College of Cambray (25
> May 1588)

The problem with this account is that, according to wikipedia and all sites that i could find, [Bruno was in Wittenberg in 1588](https://iep.utm.edu/giordano-bruno/) (had been for a few years) and left for Prague somewhen between March and June of that year (that varies across sources). To make an appearance at Cambrai in 1588 would be quite the detour...
[image]
Indeed, Bruno is attested at Cambray/Cambrai in [1586](https://iep.utm.edu/giordano-bruno/), when he left it for Wittenberg.

[Yet](https://iep.utm.edu/giordano-bruno/) what happened in 1588 was that the "Camoeracensis Acrotismus seu rationes articulorum physicorum adversus Peripateticos" came out(translation: 'Cambrai lecture, or arguments for the theses in physics against the Aristotelians') - this is,from what i can see, and, given the confusing naming scheme, if it is truly the same book ([Acrotismus seu Rationes articulorum physicorum adversus peripateticos — Wittenberg, 1588](https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/bruno1588/0015/image,info,text_ocr)) - one long rant about how bad it is that the majority shapes what is considered right and true. One part of it looks pretty close to the quote (Transcription mine):

[image]

> **Sordidi nimirum ingeny est cum multitudine, quia multitudo est, sentire velle, si quidem vulgi opinionibus & confirmatione multitorum veritas non variatur, neque ideo doctum se quispiam babere debet, quod talus habeatur**.  ------------  (Translation (bad, please feel free to improve on it): ------------ *It is, of course, a dirty mind that wants to think with the multitude because they are a multitude, if indeed the truth is not varied by the opinions of the common people & the confirmation of the multitude, and therefore no one ought to be taught to drool, because he is considered to be a fool.*)

A pretty ok match to the quote, i think. A [work on that book(s)](https://philarchive.org/archive/GIUGBO) has some insight on how it was produced: Bruno did one last speech at Cambrai, which was pretty tumultuous, he got bodily thrown out but had to swear to come back the next day to explain himself further (?) - instead he left for Wittenberg (which had already been his plan beforehand), where he authored a book that somehow is supposed to be the speech plus explanations (...or something along those lines)

Comment: If someone with Latin chops could look at my transcription and translation, that would be great. Also, as stated, the whole book seems to drive home the same message :  'Just because your wisdom is ancient and shared by the majority, doesn't make it right', so it is entirely possible that there is an even closer quote somewhere else in that book. Feel free to look. The OCR (or lack of it) makes searching not much fun.

Comment: reg "quite the detour": it was XVI century, but people were not just walking around or riding their own horses. 
Carriage services may have forced him to do that path (about coaches in the XVI century: think about Flixbus, but slower and of better quality)

Comment: @EarlGrey Regular coaches were not that much of a thing in Germany at that time, i dont thimk https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postkutsche#/media/Datei:Postkurse_1563.jpg He could have left Cambrai via coach, but shortly after that it would have gotten hairy

Comment: if by coach was hairy and difficult, then how?

Comment: @EarlGrey My guess is he travelled Wittenberg - Prague on foot (found a source for him travelling on foot from Geneva to Tolouse, which is about the double distance) - which would have taken him a bit more than a week, though there is nothing saying there was no coach to take him, just that there were no REGULAR coaches for that trip, at least according to that document i linked above. Walking source: http://www.fb10.uni-bremen.de/homepages/wildgen/pdf/kosmgedaechtnis.pdf

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not read your source, I may be proven wrong, but in general I would take the "walking" of the travellers of the time much less literally than this. In that time there was a lot of usage of spontaneus coaches as well as boats along major rivers.  From Geneve to Avignon or Arles (NW of Marseille) by boat and then to Montpellier and Toulose with a mixture of by foot and local coaches is a more realistic itinerary (or even by boat in the Mediterranean see until Carcassonne). 
See this map (from 1905, yes, not very old): [...]

Comment: http://www.emersonkent.com/images/europe_universities_map.jpg rivers were kind of highways, providing quicker travelling times for people and goods (in fact big cities were in general on major rivers)

Comment: @EarlGrey goods, maybe, but not people. Traveling on the Elbe, Wittenberg is at "Elb-km" 455, reckoned from the Czech border and ignoring the straightening of the channel that wouldn't have existed in those days. I couldn't readily find how far Prague is from that point, but it suggests a factor of at least 2.5, which is surely greater than the factor relating the speed of a horse-drawn river barge to that of land travel.

Comment: @EarlGrey Also, for long distances, horses are about as fast as people unless you can change the horses, which is expensive, and coaches of course slow the horses down, especially on bad roads.  "From Geneve to Avignon or Arles by boat": I don't see any evidence of significant navigation on the Rhone between Lyon and Geneva. There does seem to be some canalization that appears to date to the industrial revolution or later, but the towns along the river do not have significant preindustrial waterfronts. I suppose the current was too swift and the channel too shallow.

Comment: @phoog I recommend you furthering your reading horizons. There were no canal before the industrial revolution on the Rhone, sure, but the Rhone was already a very important route even in the Roman and even in the Greek time. See this study on the navigation in the Delta of the Rhone
https://journals.openedition.org/archaeonautica/528
and even Aristotle mentione it was navigated (see  https://www.linflux.com/lyon-et-region/la-batellerie-sur-le-rhone-a-travers-les-siecles/ and https://www.capsurlerhone.fr/thematique/navigation-rhone-laxe-rhone-saone/ )

Comment: @EarlGrey the first source concerns the Rhone delta, not the upper Rhone from Lyon to Geneva. The second mentions "rares bateaux à naviguer sur le Haut-Rhône, partie en amont de Lyon en raison de la force du courant" which hardly suggests that this was a normal means of travel. See also https://www.persee.fr/doc/geoca_1164-6268_1939_num_15_1_6559, which shows that through navigation from Geneva to Lyon was a longstanding unattained goal. More crucially, there seem to be no actual accounts of distance travelers going by river, so it seems that rivers enabled heavy transport rather than rapid.

Comment: @EarlGrey furthermore, as names such as Oxford, Cambridge, Frankfurt and more attest, cities were located on rivers not so much because the rivers were a convenient way to reach other cities but because they were founded at convenient places to cross the river.

Comment: @phoog The name of towns is an interesting topic. I wonder what is the meaning of Geneve and Lyon, I am sure you can elighten me. The publication you present about the Rhone river, too, albeit it is from 1939 and it just repeats vague sentences like "the navigation is known from the Roman time, but at the moment only few vessels have been found". Luckily you can visit the webapges I posted before to address the recent fluvial archeological discovery of the previous 83 years.